# Highlight a C# ListView row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, user-interface

I'm using a `ListView` in Details mode to display a list. I want to change the current index in two ways: firstly, by a mouse click (which works now), and secondly with + and - buttons. The problem is that when I click the button, the list loses focus and the row highlight disappears. How do I keep the highlight?

EDIT: Okay, I found the `HideSelection` property. But how do I change the selected index from the outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something simple like this

```
this.listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

Or you can iterate throught the list of items and find the one that you want to select.

```
private void PlusButtonClick()
{
    int newIndex = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < listView1.Items.Count; x++)
    {
        if(listItem.Selected);
        {
            listItem.Selected = false;
            newIndex = x++;
            break;
        }
    }

    this.listView1.Items[newIndex].Selected = true;
}
```